# What are the advantages and advantages of ceramic and Langevin transducers for ultrasonic cleaners?

Tags: ultrasound, piezo, piezoelectricity, cleaning, piezoelectric-effect

I have an old large ultrasonic cleaner with 5 ceramic piezo electric transducers (pictured below) epoxied to its tank's underside. They use around 40W of power each.

[image: Ceramic disc transducer]

Newer ultrasonic cleaners, however, use the more massive Langevin transducers as seen here:

[image]

What are the differences between these two types of transducers? Also, what are their respective advantages and disadvantages for the application of ultrasonic bath cleaning? Is it worth upgrading my old unit to one that uses the Langevin transducer in terms of more cleaning power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Langevin transducer *is* a piezo-ceramic transducer. However, the ceramic is under compression to prevent any tensile stresses during operation. Disadvantages for the Langevin transducer over a non-pre-stressed ceramic might be cost, weight, and bulk and the need to ensure correct pre-stress levels. The advantages of a Langevin transducer are greater predictability and reliability, possibly allowing greater power to be applied with a smaller ceramic.

[Here is a resource](http://www.ultrasonic-resonators.org/design/transducers/transducer_design.html) that you may find useful.